# frequency counter input on myDAQ not working

Tags: labview

I'm trying to measure the speed of a small DC motor using a rotary encoder and an OPTO sensor, and counter input on myDAQ.

Here's my circuit on the breadboard.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Collector pin of the transistor is connected to the DIO1 port of the myDAQ.

And here's the LabVIEW code.

[image]

On the front panel, I only have the RPM numeric indicator.

When I run the program, with the rotary encoder spinning in the gap of the OPTO coupler, nothing happens. The RPM numeric indicator keeps showing 0.

I thought the problem was my OPTO coupler. I tested it through analog input and I successfully visualised the pulses, as shown here

[image]

So the problem is not the OPTO coupler.

And I can't seem to figure out the source of the problem. I would really appreciate some help please.

Comment: Showing pictures of a breadboard is totally pointless, you need to show a circuit diagram and that part would be better served in electronics. The labview diagram is too small to be of any use.

Comment: Try opening up the time period for your measurement. Your frequency is quite slow, so with 0.1s sample time you will be getting maybe 1 transition, which will be reporting 0 freq.